# barcode scanning in android emulator

Tags: android

I'm trying to do barcode scanning using Android emulator. Could anyone
please tell me what steps to follow to do a simple barcode scanning on
the emulator?

Thank for any help,

Comment: Camera will not open in android emulator. Then, how can you scan a barcode using android emulator. Maybe this conversation helps you -

[Android emulator for Barcode scanning](http://groups.google.com/group/zxing/browse_thread/thread/06c49f2721c7da83?pli=1)

Comment: @Julien answer is the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use barcode scanner on emulator because for scanning you need a camera..so if possible then use mobile device for it..

Comment: can you send me the steps for barcode scanning in android emulator if camera included externally.

Comment: you are right hulk.But it possible in Iphone to scan barcode using emulator.So how this can be done in android emulator?

Answer (score 33):

Yes, you can set the image of wall and table from virtual scene on emulator config.[config android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh6LL.png)

Comment: This works perfectly. But in my case, i had to activate the VirtualScene option this way:
Open `Android Studio` / `Configure` / `AVD Manager`. 
Click on the pen to edit your emulator device, then `Show Advanced Settings` and finaly set Camera Back to `Virtual Scene`.

Answer (score 27):

In Android Studio,go to AVD Manager

- Choose a device then Click "Edit this device" ->
- Click Show Advanced Settings
- At camera, select Front: Emulate, Back: VirtualScene.
- Then Run App, Click ... - (icon More) at toolbar of device
- Click icon camera
- Click folder and choose image QR, then you can scale it
- Close panel, an continue run app.
- When you go to Scan QR Screen, please use ALT + QWEASD to move and control[image: This location]

  Then image will be scan

Comment: Not working for me, even this scene has been changed.

Comment: After click ..., I don't have camera option.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi It still works fine for me at the moment

Comment: @Mellon Make sure you have the camera set up for your virtual machine. Or create a new virtual machine with camera settings like I mentioned

Comment: @Mellon Example setting https://imgur.com/a/IQodA49

Comment: Sorry for late replying, it worked me after sometime. To go forward, we need to use option + W keys.

Comment: As for me **SHIFT** + ASDW works. When I turned on the camera I sow only TV, but wall and table are in another room!

Comment: Thank you! This was the only answer that worked for me. For anyone who is still struggling even with this solution, try saving the same image as a jpg in MSPaint, the emulator doesn't seem to support just any kind of image. In my case, when using a png image it was giving me this error in the command line: "loadPNG: header is not a PNG header".

Answer (score 13):

You can enable the cam on android emulator, and so use a barcode scanner on it.

To do so, you have to set the emulator property "configures camera facing back" (or front) to "yes" or "webcam0".

source : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-camera-in-android-emulator/

Answer (score 9):

Yes it is possible.
you can use the camera of your laptop as the AVD's front or back camera

[image]

Comment: This is the ANSWER!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you have a camera on your pc/laptop.

In Android Studio:

- Open `Device Manager`;
- Select the emulator device and click on `Edit` icon button;
- On `Camera` section you can find `Front` and `Back`;
- Select `Webcam` (In my case on mackbook I have `Webcam0`) in both cases ;
- Save settings and close emulator;
- On `Device Manager` select the emulator device -> 3 dots -> `Cold Boot Now`;
- Now when you open camera activity/fragment/compose_view on your emulator, android studio may requires the camera permission on your mac/windows.